# XCODE 6 change storyboard template background

Tags: xcode6, preferencescreen

I did a search on this and found many posts about changing the background color and all of them were showing result about changing the background color of the VIEWS in the project.

THIS IS NOT WHAT I WANT

I want to change the background of the default template. I like the current default template settings but when I open storyboard it has a white background and the views in it also have the same color making it hard to see.

I looked in the preferences but could not see how to change just the BG color of the storyboard layout screen

Any ideas?

Comment: This is driving me crazy. The default white is terrible. Anyone have a solution?